# After click() cancel function with popstate inside

Tags: jquery, browser-history

How to make 1st function `back_a` with popstate inside remove after `click`, 
then I can run antoner?

```
function back_a(){
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(e){
        //do some thing
    });
}
back_a();

function back_b(){
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(e){
        //do different thing
    });
}

$('btn').click(funcion(){
    // how to cancel back_a();
    //run back_b();
    back_b();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events in jquery can be namespaced:

```
$(selector).on("click.myclick", function(){...});
```

You can remove just that particular event later by doing:

```
$(selector).off("click.myclick");
```

**Edit**

Try something like this:

```
$(window).on("popstate.fubar", function(e){
    // do some stuff here
});

$('btn').click(funcion(){
    $(window).off("popstate.fubar");
    $(window).on("popstate.fubar", function(e) {
        // do some different stuff here
    });
});​
```